# Understanding classes in css

Tags: html, css, pagination

I have just started learning css. I have assumed that a class is a way of grouping styling information.

I'm trying to understand CSS pagination. In the example, it is written

```
ul.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.pagination li { display: inline;}

ul.pagination li a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

`pagination` is a class. what does it mean when they write `ul.pagination li` and 
`ul.pagination li a`?

`ul.pagination li a` has a `float left;` style. what will this achieve?

Comment: Read up on basic CSS notation

Comment: I would recommend you to try out some of this from here.http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: *what does it mean when they write ul.pagination li and  ul.pagination li a?* It means what the documentation, or the tutorial, says it does.

Comment: "*I have just started learning css*" - where from? This should definitely be covered in the tutorial, book or other resource from which you're learning. Try taking a look at the [selectors documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), from the World Wide Web Consortium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have the following code block in your HTML document:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and you would like the style this list, list items, and the links separately.

```
ul.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The CSS block above will affect your list (`<ul></ul>`).

```
ul.pagination li { 
   display: inline;
}
```

This one will affect each list item (`<li></li>`) in your list.

```
ul.pagination li a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and the last one will affect each link (`<a></a>`) inside of your list items.

`float: left` is used to have a horizontal list (for example menu). You can learn more from this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Lastly, I also suggest you to read the CSS Selectors in order to understand the logic: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read an authoritative source on CSS selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Note that the term "selector" refers to both a rule's selector (everything before the `{`) but also to individual components of the selector, so `h1.foo p.bar` is a selector, as is just `h1.foo` and `p.bar`, for example).

In response to your questions directly:

> what does it mean when they write `ul.pagination li` and `ul.pagination li  a`?

When a space character appears between two selectors (e.g. between `ul.pagination` and `li` it means "[descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)", so *any* `<li>` element which appears underneath an `<ul class="pagination">` will be matched, no matter how deep it is (as opposed to the `>` selector, as in `ul.pagination > li`, which only selects `<li>` elements that are immediate children of `<ul class="pagination">`.

CSS rules match and apply to only the deepest element in the rule, so `ul li` will only apply style rules to the `<li>`, but `ul li a` will only apply style rules to `<a>` elements.

> `ul.pagination li a` has a `float left;` style. what will this achieve?

It means that every `<a>` element that is a descendent of a `<li>` which in-turn is a descendent of a `<ul class="pagination">` will have the property `float: left` applied to it.